# How to express hypergeometric function $_3F_2(a,b,c;d,e;x) $ in terms of $_2F_1$ or $\Gamma$ functions?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I want to express the hypergeometric function  $_3F_2(a,b,c;d,e;x) $ as  $_3F_2(a,b,c;d,e;x) = \frac{\Gamma(..)}{\Gamma(...)} $. Could anyone give any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Try http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5.E2

Comment: Thank you. I checked the webpage but I couldn't reach out to a solution. Could you please guide me on how to proceed if you have any idea?

Comment: That formula with $p=2$ and $q=1$ will give you an expression in terms of $\Gamma$'s and the ${}_2 F_1$ function. That is what you requested in the title. For general $a,b,c,d,e,x$, there is no simple expression for this function.

Comment: In Eq.16.5.2, is there any solution of integral part?

Comment: As I said, there is no simple expression in general. For some specific values of the parameteres, you can evaluate the integral in terms of simple functions, but in general you cannot. If ${}_3 F_2$ was a simple function of $\Gamma$'s and ${}_2 F_1$'s, we would not have a different name and notation for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response.